# Calculating with deformed Heat equation?

Tags: differential-equations, physics

How can I implement the following equation and start computing numerically?
[image]

The first partial derivative can take fractional numbers.

Comment: "partial derivative can take fractional numbers" - fractional derivatives are not yet fully supported in *Mathematica*, so the hard work of discretizing this fractional PDE is up to you.

Comment: Could you point me to an application example where a heat equation with a fractional time derivative is needed? I'd need to see that, then I can possibly guide you to a solution.

Comment: @user21, [this article](https://www.intechopen.com/online-first/a-review-on-fractional-differential-equations-and-a-numerical-method-to-solve-some-boundary-value-pr) has a pretty good overview, but for the specific case of fractional heat/diffusion equations, please look at [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apnum.2007.06.003) or [this](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsta.2012.0146) (among many other references).

Comment: @J.M., thanks for the links.